# How do I anonymize contact data in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I need to send a copy of my MongoDB to Sitecore Support for investigation. For security reasons I want all sensitive data to be anonymized.

Fields I'm talking about are: FirstName, LastName, Addresses and Email addresses.

**Is there an easy and fast way to do this?**

My Contacts collection contains around 350.000 entries.

Comment: Have you taken a look at https://github.com/sunitparekh/data-anonymization to see if this will work for your needs? Looks like a Ruby project that specializes in data-anonymization and has MongoDB support/example. I haven't used this before, so I can't comment on how well it works

Comment: That looks like a good long term solution. Now I just want a quick way to do it. I've tested Dmytro's answer and it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can mass-replace personal data right from the MongoDB console:

```
var i = 0;
db.Contacts.find({}, {_id: 1}).forEach(function(contact) {
  db.Contacts.update({_id: contact._id}, {$set: {
    "Personal.FirstName": "RandomFirstName" + i,
    "Personal.Surname": "RandomSurname" + i
    /* etc. for other personal data */
  }});
  i++;
})
```